# gstreamer vaapi problem

Tags: 10.04, video, 64-bit, gstreamer

I installed gstreamer-vaapi from this PPA :

ppa:guido-iodice/video

sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-vaapi libgstvaapi-x11-0 libgstvaapi0

but, if I run totem movie player (via terminal) it's show this error :

> `(totem:3383): GLib-GObject-WARNING **:
>   g_object_set_valist: object class
>   'TotemScrsaver' has no property named
>   'reason'`
>
> `(totem:3383): GLib-GObject-WARNING **:
>   value "10752000" of type 'guint' is
>   invalid or out of range for property
>   'connection-speed' of type 'guint'
>   libva: libva version 0.31.0 Xlib: 
>   extension "XFree86-DRI" missing on
>   display ":0.0". libva:
>   va_getDriverName() returns 0 libva:
>   Trying to open
>   /usr/lib/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so libva
>   error:
>   /usr/lib/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so init
>   failed libva: va_openDriver() returns
>   -1 Segmentation fault`

It's seems I get wrong nvidia_drv_video.so. What should I do?

If I uninstall it, it's work fine, but I want to use this vaapi backend for my video decoding via GPU while I run gstreamer based apps.

PS :

I use Ubuntu Lucid 64bit and MSI CR 400 Notebook :

- Intel Core 2 Duo
- Nvidia 8200M

Answer (score 1):

If you are certainly using the nvidia proprietary driver then it's probably a problem with the PPA package and you should report the problem to Guido Iodice:

https://launchpad.net/~guido-iodice

Answer (score 0):

Before install driver or other software 
- need down gui, possible example for ubuntu:
$ sudo service gdm stop
$ sudo ... install drivers ...
$ sudo reboot
$ sudo service gdm stop
$ sudo ... install software ...
$ sudo reboot
$ sudo ... test you media player

P.S. Sorry for my bad english

## tvlm@jubber.ru